# Is it possible to mock a controller and have access to the FormTagLib in the same unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

As the title states, is it possible to have a unit test for a controller, and mock a tag lib?

As it stands, I have a User controller. Many of the actions use the

```
g.message(code: 'something.something')
```

call to set a message on the page.

```
@TestFor(UserController)
@Mock(User)
@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification
{
    UserService userServiceMock = Mock(UserService)

def setup()
{
    controller.userService = userServiceMock
}

def cleanup()
{
}

void "test manageDevice"()
{
    given:
        def g = mockTagLib(FormTagLib)
    when:
        controller.manageDevice()
    then:
        model.pageTitle == 'message.device'
}
```

With that code I'm trying to hit the controller action but because of the g.message, it's failing with an error saying that it can't set a value to null. Pretty much because it doesn't see the "g.message"

I'm a little unsure if my unit test needs written differently, or if I'm just missing something.

Any help would be great!

EDIT:

Some updates using messageSource:

```
    void "test manageDevice"()
    {
    given:
        messageSource.addMessage 'user.devices', request.locale, 'Manage Devices'
    when:
        controller.manageDevices()
    then:
        assertEquals model.pageTitle == 'user.devices', controller.flash.message
    }
```

It seems to still be complaining because it doesn't have context of the "g" namespace on the controller. I'll note as well, I don't have context of 'addMessage' from messageSource. Not sure why, it should be there.

In the same controller, and many others, the only taglib we use in the controller scope is 'g' for the 'g.message' set in each action. The only other call that's being done, is one using the 'g' for a call like 'g.fixRedisIssue'

Comment: Have a look at [Testing Calling Tag Libraries](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html). You need to add a message using `messageSource` bean in the test.

Comment: Instead of using g.message() in your controller, can you use it in your GSP with the <g:message> tag? It would also make your model smaller (simpler to maintain).

Comment: Probably.. that's how we have it throughout the entire application. The message there is just used to return a message to the view. So it's used in situations where we return an error to the view and it's a flash message on the page.

Comment: @dmahapatro I gave that a try, and i'm working through issues with it, but that'll work for the message. But in certain instances we're using the g namespace for other actions besides the messages. So it wouldn't work for a situation like that.

Comment: Using form tag lib other than formats/message in model and controller layer is an over kill. Can you post the way you tried using `messageSource` and how other taglibs are used in the controller? May be there is a better alternative to that.

Comment: Updated issue @dmahapatro

Comment: Can you post the code of the action of the controller you want to test?

Comment: @ramsharen the example at the beginning of my post are the contents of the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a unit test for a controller with a mocked TagLib by including the necessary TagLib classes in the value of the `grails.test.mixin.Mock` annotation on the Spec class.  For example, if you have the following TagLib:
<sub>(based on code in [Grails documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingTagLibraries))</sub>

```
package org.grails.samples

class SimpleTagLib {
    static namespace = 'g'
    def hello = { attrs, body ->
        out << "Hello ${attrs.name ?: 'World'}"
    }
}
```

And you have the following controller:

```
package org.grails.samples

class SimpleController {
    def flashHello() {
        flash.message = g.hello()
    }
}
```

You could test it with the following specification:

```
package org.grails.samples

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SimpleController)
@Mock(SimpleTagLib)
class SimpleControllerSpec extends Specification {
    void 'test flashHello'() {
        when:
        controller.flashHello()
        then:
        flash.message == 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

If you have multiple classes to mock, you can specify them in an array argument to `@Mock`.  So you can add any necessary tag libraries to `UserControllerSpec` by changing `@Mock(User)` to something like `@Mock([User, FormTagLib, YourFixRedisIssueTagLib])`.  However, I'd be surprised if you actually did need to add `FormTagLib` because in my Grails testing it seems to be included by default.

As some further advice, some of the code you posted doesn't make any sense.  Specifically:

```
assertEquals model.pageTitle == 'user.devices', controller.flash.message
```

Decide specifically what you want to test for and focus on writing the simplest code possible for that.

Also, based on your description of what's happening, I think that you're getting thrown off because your IDE is not properly integrated with Grails to see the `g` context.

Comment: Works for me! I ended up finding a way to work with this after getting over a few hurdles.. but this works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the message text to the view from the controller, why not return the message code instead? For example, if you have something like this in your view:

```
<p>${flash.message}</p>
```

You can replace it with this:

```
<p><g:message code="${flash.code}" /></p>
```

And then set the code in the controller:

```
flash.code = "user.devices"
```

Then you'll be able to test the controller methods painlessly :)